# apache flink sink for elasticserach NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, sink

I am writing a Flink job to send a data stream to elasticsearch. I am using Maven and IntelliJ. When I try to test the job within IntelliJ I get the following error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/connector/sink2/Sink

the job code is quite simple, see below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
        input = params.get("input");
        
        //1. creao un stream execution environment
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        //2. creo un data stream da una fonte
        DataStream<String> inputdatastream = env.addSource(new ProvaDataSource());
        //3. faccio x con il datas stream

        //4. manda il risultato di 3 ad un data sink, es .print()
        inputdatastream.sinkTo(
                new Elasticsearch7SinkBuilder<String>()
                        .setBulkFlushMaxActions(1) 
                        .setHosts(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"))
                        .setEmitter(
                                (element, context, indexer) ->
                                        indexer.add(new IndexRequest("my-index")
                                                        .id(element)
                                                        .source(element)))
                        .build());

        //5 esegui
        env.execute(Example2.class.getName());
    }
```

Any suggestion about what to change?

I have been checking the dependencies and got the latest available in the apache flink website (I am using flink version 1.17.1) see below:

```
           <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch7</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-1.17</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I already cleared and rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 0):

With IntelliJ it is necessary to select the "Add dependencies with provided scope to classpath" option in the run configuration.

[image]